# Editor for 2D graphical elements in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, graphics, quartz-2d

I am going to be working with a graphic designer to develop an interactive children's iphone app. It will not be a game as such, but rather a series of backgrounds with some interactive objects that can be touched to display simple animation or sound.

These I would be striving for the quality that these guys produce http://duckduckmoosedesign.com/

I assume that they would be using Quartz2D rather than embedded jpegs for their design elements?

I was wondering what tools people would recommend for designers to use that can then be imported for use an iPhone app.

I have seen some references to creating SVG in Inkscape but was wondering whether there was any other alternatives for importing graphics into Quartz for use in an iPhone app?

Answer (score 2):

[Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/) is a design app, that is capable to output quartzCore source code suitable for iphone or mac.